# SetThreadExecutionState with ES_CONTINUOUS - what happens if app crashes before resetting flags

Tags: c++, winapi

I am going to use `SetThreadExecutionState` WinAPI function to keep system running during a certain job.

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28VS.85%29.aspx), application must clear the flags set after the job is done if `ES_CONTINUOUS` is used.

If my application crashed during the job, I would not be able to clear the flags that were set earlier. My question is, will the system clear the flags set by the app when app terminates or will the system remain awake?

Comment: When you say "will *it* remain awake", what is the "it" you are referring to?

Comment: 'it' refers to the system. I corrected the question

Comment: So your question is really whether a thread that no longer exists can have an execution state?

Comment: I didn't think much about the name of the method before posting the question. Now I understand that the name of the method itself had the answer for my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the system will clear (or, more accurately, discard) the flags when the thread that set them no longer exists.

It doesn't matter whether the thread exited cleanly or was terminated.

*NB: I can only confirm from my own experience that the flags will be ignored once the process has exited, but the name of the function strongly implies that the flags are set per-thread rather than per-process.*

Answer (score 3):

According to the [System Sleep Criteria](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373233.aspx) documentation:

> The system maintains a count of applications that have called SetThreadExecutionState. **The system tracks each thread that calls SetThreadExecutionState** and adjusts the counter accordingly. If this counter reaches zero and there has not been any user input, the system enters sleep.

So it is conceivable, even likely, that if the app crashes and the calling thread disappears, the system will know and adjust the counter accordingly, much like it does for most other thread-sensitive resources.